# Jenkins module building even after build killed

Tags: jenkins

Sometimes when we kill a build on Jenkins, on its job page it will say the build was aborted, but if we click on the build, it will say the module is still building. It is building a java project.

So, even after we kill the build, our tests are still being executed. I've even restarted the slave they were running on and the module still says it is being built. There is a progress bar with a stop button for the module, but nothing happens when clicking that either.

Any ideas on how, or what I should be doing differently, to stopping builds more effectively?

Comment: What are you building here ? Which technology ?

Comment: I've updated the main post. We are using Jenkins to build java projects.

Comment: Its a bug reported in Jenkins --- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-10840